# What is the most concise way of pulling database objects from a db into a list?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have been writing database software for a few years now and know that there are multiple ways to access data. Personally I do everything manually when pulling data by using a data reader object. This has just started to get on my nerves when working with tables that have a large amount of columns. It becomes very inefficient to have to write 30 lines of this code at a time

```
if(reader[count] != DBNull.Value)
   someObject = reader.GetString(count++);
else
   count++;
```

it is bad enough that the queries themselves take a long time to type out and get ready.

I was thinking on possibly using a datatable to retrieve my records since you can do that in a few lines and then write a few helper methods that iterate throught the rows and return me an observable collection of objects. Is there another more simple, or more concise way to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you ever listen about entity framework or another orm?

Comment: ... or the lightweight [Dapper.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET) used by stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Holy wackamole! That looks friggen sweet. Gonna do some more research into this and ORM's in general.

Comment: I made a Nuget package called LaunchReader which will take an IDataReader and return you an IEnumerable<T>. Two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the datatable

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
     conn.Open();

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from mytable", conn))
     {
          adapter.Fill(dt);
     }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question though